# Python error integer is required

Tags: python

I'm trying to stress test my EC2 Micro instance using Python.

I'm getting an error which seems self-explanatory but thats not the case:

**Error:** an integer is required

**stress_test function:**

```
try:
    bytes = random._urandom(512)
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((self.host, int(self.port)))
    s.setblocking(0)
    s.sendto(bytes, (self.host, self.port))
except Exception, e:
    print(str(e))
```

**main function:**

```
  while True:
    if threading.activeCount() < thread_limit:
        stress_test(host_ip, host_port).start()
```

The error is on this line: `s.sendto(bytes, (self.host, self.port))`

However, If I try converting it to init I would of course get an `invalid literal for int() with base 10` error.

I have also tried `s.sendto(bytes(512), (self.host, self.port))` but then I get `'str' object is not callable` error.

What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self.port` needs to be an integer; use `int(self.port)` in the sendto line.